# Как осуществить qSort на JAVA?

Tags: java, сортировка

Не могу интегрировать алгоритм qSort в свой код. Нужно, что массив продуктов был отсортирован по ЦЕНЕ по возрастающей. Метод оставил пустым, так как не получается с ним разобраться.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Product[] products = {new Product(24, "Bread", "Soft and tasty"), new Product(15, "Bubble gum", "Makes u love it!"), new Product(95, "Chips", "So crispy, so yummy!")};
    Arrays.sort(products); 
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(products));
  }
}
public class Product implements Comparable<Product> {
  private String name;
  private int price;
  private String description;

  public Product(int price, String name, String description) {
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
    this.description = description;
  }

  void mySort(Product[] products) {
 }
```

Comment: Нужно все таки написать, что не получается. В текущем виде это "решите за меня задачу", а это недопустимый тут вид вопроса.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Product> products = Arrays.asList(new Product(24, "Bread", "Soft and tasty"), new Product(15, "Bubble gum", "Makes u love it!"), new Product(95, "Chips", "So crispy, so yummy!"));
    List<Product> sortProduct = products.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(Product::getPrice)).collect(Collectors.toList());

    sortProduct.forEach((c) -> System.out.println(c.getPrice()));


}
```

Чтобы заработало, в Ваш класс Product надо добавить геттеры и сеттеры.

Comment: это все прекрасно, только Array.sort реализован при помощи алгоритма «сортировка слиянием» или «merge sort»

Comment: @StrangerintheQ в коде вопрощающего я не увидел ничего похожего на реализацию каких то алгоритмов, зато увидел желание отсортировать ArrayList ))

Comment: там упомянут qSort, то бишь quick sort

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, ну можно вытащить примитивы из Product и отсортировать Array.sort, тогда будет быстрая сортировка ))

Comment: @StrangerintheQ большое спасибо, ребята! разобрался с qSort! но можно и было через  Мёрдж, полезная инфа! спасибо!

Comment: @AlekseiGaile большое спасибо, ребята! разобрался с qSort! но можно и было через Мёрдж, полезная инфа! спасибо